# CS50 PSET4 pointers

Tags: c, pointers, cs50

I am attempting [CS50 PSET4](https://cdn.cs50.net/2014/x/psets/4/pset4/pset4.html).
Can someone explain why the first works instead of the second?

Essentially what I did was, I declare char* colour outside the loop in the first and declared char* color inside all of my if statements in the second.

This worked when I declared char* outside of the if statements

```
 void initBricks(GWindow window)
 {
    char* colour;
    // TODO
    for(int i=0,y=20;i < ROWS; i++)
    { 
        y+= 30;

      for(int j=0,x=5,c=0;j < COLS; j++)
      {
        if(i==0)
        colour = "RED";

        if(i==1)
        colour = "BLUE";

        if(i==2)
        colour = "CYAN";

        if(i==3)
        colour ="ORANGE";

        if(i==4)
        colour = "GRAY";

        GRect brick = newGRect(x,y,30,15);
        setFilled(brick,true);
        setColor(brick, colour);
        add(window, brick);       
        x+= 40;       


      }
   }   
}
```

But this didn't work, when I declared char* inside all the if statements

```
void initBricks(GWindow window)
{
    // TODO
    for(int i=0,y=20;i < ROWS; i++)
    { 
        y+= 30;

      for(int j=0,x=5,c=0;j < COLS; j++)
      {
        if(i==0)
        char *colour = "RED";

        if(i==1)
        char *colour = "BLUE";

        if(i==2)
        char *colour = "CYAN";

        if(i==3)
        char *colour ="ORANGE";

        if(i==4)
        char *colour = "GRAY";

        GRect brick = newGRect(x,y,30,15);
        setFilled(brick,true);
        setColor(brick, colour);
        add(window, brick);       
        x+= 40;       

     }
   }   
}
```

I am fairly new to pointers but so far I sort of understand that char* is sort of the equivalent of a string where it points to the address of the variable, colour, in this case.

However, I am not sure why I don't have to put in the `'&'` (reference operator) when I use it in `setColor(brick, colour)`.

Answer (score 1):

To see why the second group of code doesn't work it may be helpful to see it as:

```
    if (i==0) {
        char *colour = "RED";
    }

    if (i==1) {
        char *colour = "BLUE";
    }
```

You can see more easily that the declaration of `colour` extends only to the end of the block, so that `colour` no longer exists when the next statement is executed.

As for your second question, `setColor` is only using the value of `colour`, (which is already a pointer) so no need to pass a reference to it.  `setcolor` can access the string without the reference.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the second set doesn't work is that you are attempting to modify a string literal (char *colour = "foo") which is not allowed in C.

As an aside, both versions have undefined behavior, and you should consider compiling with all of the -W flags on.